# Windows_Run_command_syntax to use with ACL Execute Command

Tags: windows, syntax, command

My business would like to run Able2Extract via an ACL script. The ACL command is Execute and I was able to open Able2Extract using the following syntax:

EXECUTE 'cmd /c "C:\Program Files\Investintech.com Inc\Able2Extract Professional 14.0\Able2ExtractPro.exe"'

Now I need Windows command syntax to tell Able2Extract to "Open" (shortcut per Able2Extract is Ctrl + O) and grab a specified PDF.

After the PDF is imported, I want to Select "All" (for the entire PDF) and then Select Excel for Convert to File Type. Next select Convert Automatic and then save resulting excel document.

Comment: I used some older version several years ago, I think they had a batch converter, did they remove it in the new versions?

Comment: I looked it up and it appears I could make a .bat file. I also have the task scheduler although it isn't something I want to schedule. It will run as part of an Audit Command Language (ACL) script, but the language needs to be windows command syntax. How do I tell Able2Extract to open a given PDF and select ALL? I am unfamiliar with basic command syntax and when I look on line it is mostly for the utilities.

Comment: They probably have some safeguards for that. This might be illegal to do... They have some API for the purpose of automation...